# Grid com indice único

Tags: javascript, html, grid

Olá, qual é o melhor jeito de fazer um grid por Javascript e HTML? Eu preciso que eu possa desenhar ou mudar a cor da area de cada espaço em branco. Fiz desse jeito mais ele não me atende por que quando tento mudar a cor de um único quadrado ele acaba mudando ou da linha inteira ou da coluna inteira.

```
for(var i = 0;i < linha;i++) {
    for (var n = 0;n < coluna;n++) {
        grid_x[i] = i * 40;
        grid_y[n] = n * 40;
        res_x[i] = i * 40;
        res_y[n] = n * 40;
        c[i] = false * i
        dRs(grid_x[i],grid_y[n],grid_w,grid_h,1,"#747474",c[i])
    }
}
function dRs(x,y,w,h,l,s,c) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth= l;
    context.strokeStyle= s;
    context.rect(x,y,w,h);      
    context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: O que quer dizer com `grid`? tabela? O que faz a função `dRs()`?

Comment: Desculpa esqueci de explicar no tópico. dRs() desenha quadrados com strokes, a parte c[i] não faz parte do código. Com grid quero dizer isso: http://simcity1re.6te.net/ , só que sem as funções de desenhar, essa é uma versão muito antiga do que estou fazendo.

Comment: E o que são os parametros dessa função? não está muito claro o que quer fazer. Quer mudar a cor dentro do `for` ou posteriormente?

Comment: Quero mudar a cor de cada quadrado separadamente por clique. Exemplo: se eu clicar no quadrado do meio ele ficará preto sem transformar nenhum outro quadrado em preto também.

Comment: Prefiro JS puro.

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/Kj8N7/

Comment: Sérgio, queria te agradecer e pedir mais uma coisa eu entendi boa parte do código porém não conhecia o que você fez (apply,concat e forEach) você pode me recomendar um site que me mostre esse tipo de função (não sei se seria uma função) padrão do Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Deny se a intenção é criar um jogo sugiro que você procure uma engine para te auxiliar pois existem várias outras questões que não somente muda ra cor ou realizar um evento.

A jsgamesoup é muito simples e cheia de exemplos. pode ser um ponto de partida inicial.

Também aqui tem um exemplo simples de como resolver a sua questão :

[mudacor grid](http://jsfiddle.net/bbefnnoL/)

Lembrando que se trabalha com eventos, onclick, e para cada mudança é necessário realizar a "pintura" novamente das grids.

[engine jsgamesoup](http://jsgamesoup.net/)